# Google Cloud trial ended, upgraded to paid but websites are offline

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, offline

I was using Google Cloud as trial, suddenly all my websites were stopped and Google said my trial ended and asked me to upgrade, I did and I can access plesk, but all my websites continue offline. I restarted plesk (port 8443) services and I rebooted the instances but the websites continue offline.
In the firewall it says there are rules to allow http and https 
Do you know what may be causing this problem after the services were stopped and restarted by upgrading the trial account to a paid one?

PS: ///SOLVED/// : What happened is Google changed my servers IPs, only the last IP segment changed and I didn't notice it, sorry for opening the thread.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is Google changed my servers IPs, only the last IP segment changed and I didn't notice it, sorry for opening the thread. Thank you very much.